# Allow only a list of IP's on iptables

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, iptables

I have an apache server with wordpress installed and I need to determine just a few IP's that will have access to the website (I have a list of IP's)... what would be the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Example file:

```
192.168.168.1
192.168.168.2
192.168.168.3
```

So in your iptables rule set script file put somewhere appropriate the following lines:

```
whitelist="/path/to/the/example/file/with/the/whitelist/ips.txt"
while IFS= read -r wips; do # wips stands for whitelist IPs
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "${wips}" -j ACCEPT
done < "${whitelist}"
```

Please note when I said "iptables rule set script file" I meant a shell script that has all of your custom rules that you would like to apply in your iptables config.
Note number two: the `-i eth0` is an assumption that your default ethernet card is named eth0. it could also be eth1, eth2, ethX or enp0s1, enp0s2 enpXsX. Use what is appropriate for you.
To check if the above script, was successfully applied run the following command:

```
iptables -L INPUT
```

Comment: Note that `ACCEPT` rule only has a point if the chain policy is `DROP` (or if there's a "fallback" `DROP` / `REJECT` rule).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a plenty of addresses/networks, the best solution will be to store them using ipset [1].

[1] https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ipset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `firewalld` you can utilize the `rich rules`.

**Example :-**

`firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=192.168.1.101/32 service name=telnet limit value=1/m accept'`

You can read more about rich rules in [here](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html).

Above said is the **recommended** way of controlling access to resources (ports/services). Only drawback is that the `source address` parameter takes single argument or `network CIDR`, so you will have to script the list of `IP addresses` if you have plenty of them or you can do the opposite, block all and allow only the ones you want.